# How to handle 'request is too large for API to list' error?

Tags: python, json, github-api

I want to get a list of contributors to the /torvalds/linux repository on github. But I receive this error that the result is too large and API can't list it. what should I do?

Specifically, I write this code:

```
from pprint import pprint

response = requests.get('https://api.github.com/repos/torvalds/linux/contributors', auth=(Github_username, Github_password))
pprint(response.json())
```

I get this as output:

{'documentation_url': 'https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-contributors',
 'message': 'The history or contributor list is too large to list contributors '
            'for this repository via the API.'}

Comment: This is coming *from the API*, **not** from your python code. It's their data, and they decide how and what to serve to your request.

Comment: you may need to open a bug with them, because per the documentation I don't think this is expected response from your request.

Comment: I have this same problem.  Were you able to solve it?